# Error on unity is not letting me install package from git url

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, gitlab, xcrun, lts

I'm supposed to add the package from this link to my project https://gitlab.com/eventlabprojects/quickvr.packages/com.quickvr.quickbase.git
but it's not working. It worked for everyone in my class but me, and I'm not sure if it's because of the Mac I have or what exactly.

I'm using the installer Unity LTS for silicon:

[image]

My Mac is the 14-inch 2021 MacBook Pro with the Apple M1 Pro chip and it's updated to Mac OS Ventura 13.0.1.

This is the error that keeps popping up, something about xcrun?
[image]

P.S. I'm not a developer, I'm a student who is trying Unity for the first time and STRUGGLING.

> [Package Manager Window] Error adding package: https://gitlab.com/eventlabprojects/quickvr.packages/com.quickvr.quickbase.git.
> Unable to add package [https://gitlab.com/eventlabprojects/quickvr.packages/com.quickvr.quickbase.git]:
>
>   Error when executing git command. xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

Comment: In cases like that it really helps to post the error message to your question [**as text and NOT as image**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Maybe related? https://bobcares.com/blog/xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path/ or also here (using same solution) https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a

Comment: btw, there is a problem in the console on your screenshot.

Comment: She doesn't know either...

Comment: @Morion I'm pretty sure that's the point ... ^^

Comment: @derhugo It worked! Thank you so much!